# React Native: Uses autolinking for native dependencies "react-native-maps"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I have the `react-native-maps` installed in my project. While run in android i get the following Error.

> React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
>     - react-native-maps (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-maps")
>   This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink " and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.

To fix this error I run `react-native unlink react-native-maps` commands but I still have this error.

Environment:

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.4",
```

Comment: Did you try to link it manually `react-native link react-native-maps`

Comment: No i didn't manually link @Neeeko

Answer (score 1):

If you added manually map dependency in `build.gradle` file or something changed in `MainApplication.java` than this kind of error is showing. please check your `build.gradle` file, `setting.gradlew` file, `MainApplication.java` file.

[image: please check attached image]